# Input 3 characters to produce 4 letter strings

Tags: java, permutation

I'm trying to create a java program that takes 3 different characters which then produces all possible 4 letter combinations of the 3 characters. e.g an input of `a b c` would produce...

`abca` `abcb` `abcc` `aabc` `abbc`...

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Comment: If I do your homework do I get the grade as well?

Comment: Is `aaaa` also valid combination?

Comment: I will grade you as this isn't homework... sorry should have stated. I actually want to create this to test a program I have created.

Comment: Yes `aaaa` is also valid

Comment: @M0rty Can you show the code/work you have done until now?

Comment: If length of expected word is small you can simply use nested loops. If length can be dynamic you can use recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following program should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] alphabet = new char[] {'a','b','c'};
        possibleStringsOfLengthK(4, alphabet, "");
    }
    public static void possibleStringsOfLengthK(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String currentValue) {
        if(currentValue.length() == maxLength) {
            System.out.println(currentValue);
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
                String oldValue = currentValue;
                currentValue += alphabet[i];
                possibleStringsOfLengthK(maxLength, alphabet, currentValue);
                currentValue = oldValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

The output is (reading from left to right, top to bottom) :

```
aaaa aaab aaac aaba aabb aabc aaca aacb aacc 
abaa abab abac abba abbb abbc abca abcb abcc 
acaa acab acac acba acbb acbc acca accb accc 
baaa baab baac baba babb babc baca bacb bacc 
bbaa bbab bbac bbba bbbb bbbc bbca bbcb bbcc 
bcaa bcab bcac bcba bcbb bcbc bcca bccb bccc 
caaa caab caac caba cabb cabc caca cacb cacc 
cbaa cbab cbac cbba cbbb cbbc cbca cbcb cbcc
ccaa ccab ccac ccba ccbb ccbc ccca cccb cccc
```

This will give you some idea and you can further optimize it. You may
also need to verify it for all test cases and may need to edit as per
your requirements.

**Hint:** How about `StringBuilder` and enhanced-loop?

Comment: I'm not sure the whole outut is important, and it is pretty annoying for readers. I'm going to split it in columns

Comment: @Dici: The whole point of the complete output is to assure nothing is missed. You can split it in columns.

Comment: @MarquisBlount you beat me to this :D I tried to be clever with Sublime multiple carets and failed to do it quickly haha